Multiparameter classes versus data types
It often happens that we get to choose between writing a (often multiparameter) class or using some (sometimes n-ranked) data type. Let me give two examples to clarify my point:
Example 1
An action of a semigroup on another is defined as the following multiparameter class. This is more or less the approach use in the monoid-extras library
--   Instances must satisfy the following law:
--
--   act s1 (act s2 x) === act (s1 <> s2) x
--
class Semigroup s => Action s x where
  act :: s -> x -> x

Alternatively, I could define an Action using a data structure, for instance
newtype Action s x = Action {act :: s -> x -> x}

Example 2
The same kind of trade off appears for lenses. You can either define lenses as data types as it is done in the lens library and then define view and set using the lens.
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t

Alternatively, one could imagine to write a multiparameter class where view and set follow the lenses laws :
class Lens s a where
  view :: s -> a
  set :: a -> s -> s

Question
I can see many advantages in using a simple data type instead of a typeclass. I feel it would probably better to use actions as elements of some type (that is the newtype I proposed). Somehow, I feel that there is something philosophically wrong in using multiparameter type classes to express some kind of relationship between two types.
When do you use multiparameter classes and when do you prefer using a data type when faced the above dilemma ? Is the Action implementation of monoid-extras wrong ?

The "simple data type" approach allows you to pass different actions for the same semigroup and same x. The "typeclass" approach only allows one action, but does not require you to explicitly specify it at each call. I believe it is useful to think as typeclasses as a mechanism to pass parameters implicitly where such values are uniquely determined by the types in play.
